# Auto sync (replication) mysql or PostgreSQL master-master avoiding conflicts

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-replication, database

I have two server one in cloud host and the other local in my office

I want a tool if my office get down of the internet or any reason, when its get up it will sync auto

Is there a lazy way to solve the conflicts?

Any suggestion?

Comment: you do not define your current set up, but edit your question to ask about "solving conflicts".. Perhaps you should rewrite your question to the usual format; "what is the expected behavior", "what is the current behavior", "what is the exact error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution by using this tool,
[**RubeyRep**](http://www.rubyrep.org/)
its providing asynchronous replication and syncing option,
in my case i can have master - master with out worrying about if the internet is got down delay lets say 1 minute or 2 minutes, its fine in my case,

> **Scan Features**
>
> rubyrep can scan corresponding tables of left and right database3 for
>   diverging data.
>
> - Different output modes: from count of differences over row diffs to full row dumps.
> - `enter code here`Low bandwidth mode available: reduced number of round-trips; only actual differences go through the network.
> - Shows progress bar with estimated remaining amount of work.
>
> **Sync Features**
>
> - All scan features also apply to syncs
> - Automatically orders table syncs to avoid foreign key conflicts.
> - Sync policy specifyable: ignore deletes in left database, ignore    created records in right database, etc.
> - Prebuild conflict resolution methods available: left db wins, right    db wins
> - Custom conflict resolution methods specifiable via ruby code snippets
> - Merge decisions can optionally be logged in the rubyrep event log    table.
>     **Replication Features**
> - Automatically sets up necessary triggers, log tables, etc.
> - Automatically discovers newly added tables and synchronizes the table    content
> - Automatically reconfigures sequences to avoid duplicate key conflicts
> - Tracks changes to primary key columns
> - Can implement both master-slave and master-master replication
> - Prebuild conflict resolution methods availble: left / right wins;    earlier / later change wins
> - Custom conflict resolution specifiable via ruby code snippets
> - Replication decisions can optionally be logged in the rubyrep event    log table][2](http://www.rubyrep.org/features.html)

Answer (score -1):

It's called replication and you can set up a master in your office and your cloud machine can be slave: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

> Data security - because data is replicated to the slave, and the slave
>   can pause the replication process, it is possible to run backup
>   services on the slave without corrupting the corresponding master
>   data.

Comment: My cloud will get read/write permission so it should be master-master but if i did it in this way and my office get down my database will get conflicts

Comment: So you are writing changes to the cloud. Then make your office the slave. Master master does not work like that. Updated the answer to add data backup from the docs.

Comment: If i add it slave and internet is gone down how can i use write functionality, the point of having local server in my office to work offline

Comment: Then use my first assumption. Write and read from your local server; set that server up as a master. Use your cloud machine as a slave.

Comment: In this case users whom using cloud and office server is down cant write, i want to read/write in cloud and office

Comment: Then you might consider using nosql, which queues changes to be processed on multiple duplicate database instances

Comment: I found this tool http://www.rubyrep.org/features.html ,i saw couchdb its amazing in clustering, but i need to integrate it with lucene for full index search which is a complex setup

Comment: perhaps you should consider asking a (properly formatted) question on serverfault.com